# assigning an address to a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I wanted to know if there are alternative ways of assigning a pointer the address of the value its pointing to. For example, there's the usual way:

```
int a = 10;
int *ptr;
ptr = &a;
```

but at some places I see it declared like:

```
int *ptr = &a;
```

Are both of these ways equivalent? I am slightly confused because I always considered *ptr as giving the *value* of a, and not the address. Could anyone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: When writing `int *ptr;` you declare a pointer. When writing *ptr you assign à value. Its the déclaration that changes the meaning of the * operator

Comment: You could also write `int a = 10, *ptr = &a;` :) They're the same thing

Comment: First and second example are not the same, but does the same result. 1) First one declares `int *ptr;` and then takes place the assigment `ptr = &a;` 2) Second: `int *ptr = &a;` here declaration  and initialization are taking place .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am slightly confused because I always considered `*ptr` as giving the value of `a`, and not the address.

It is indeed a bit confusing as `*` is used to declare a pointer, and also used as the dereference operator. The actual meaning of `*` depends on the context - whether is used in a declaration, an initialisation or an assignment.

It's worth knowing the differences between 1) declaration, 2) initialisation, and 3) assignment.

```
int *ptr; // 1) this is declaration without initialisation.

int *ptr = &a; // 2) this is declaration **and** initialisation (initialise ptr to the address of variable a)

int b = 10;
*ptr = b;   // 3) this is assignment, assign what pointed by ptr to value of variable b.
```

- In 1) the `*` means that `ptr` is a pointer to `int` (but it has not pointed to any valid location yet).
- In 2) the `*` means that `ptr` is a pointer to `int`, and its initial value is the address of variable `a`.
- In 3) the `*` is the dereference operator, ie assigning what pointed by `ptr` to the value of variable `b`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand it a lot better now :)

Answer (score 2):

No ..it is declaration and intiliaziation in one line.

This will clear the idea..

```
typedef int* intp;

intp ptr=&a;
```

Equivalently

```
intp ptr; //int *ptr;
ptr=&a;   // ptr=&a;
```

Answer is :  YES they are equivalent.

You may ask-
:- **How do a compiler understand?(whether * is indirection or as in declaration)**

Ans:- C is context sensitive..based on the context on which it is used compiler decides it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

`int *ptr; ptr = &a;` is to `int *ptr = &a;` as `int n; n = 3;` is to `int n = 3;`.

That is, pointer declaration and initialisation is no different to normal variables. I prefer to use one line whenever possible since then there is less danger of having uninitialised variables.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know it does seem a little less hazardous to use the one-liner, will try to use that approach more.

Answer (score 2):

> Are both of these ways equivalent?

Yes.

The second one is marginally preferred as the first one leaves `ptr` unassigned until the last line (though in practise a compiler would probably optimise that out).

> I am slightly confused because I always considered *ptr as giving the value of a, and not the address.

You are confusing the syntax declaring a variable with the syntax for using that variable.

```
int *ptr;
```

just declares a variable called `ptr` that is a pointer to an integer.

```
int *ptr = &a;
```

does exactly the same. The first part is still just the declaration of the pointer as before. The part after the equals sign initialises `ptr` to the address of `a`

You are correct that after declaration when you later use this variable in subsequent code specifying `*ptr` will give you the contents of the pointer (in this case the value of `a`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped in clearing up the concept. I wasn't expecting so many answers, and every answer is helping me in understanding the concept, so won't be able to accept your answer. But thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem @QPTR, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If `*` operator is used at the time of declaration then it's just used to indicate the type of variable being declared. Whereas in all other cases `*` operator is used as dereference operator (except where it's used as multiplication operator).

So `int *ptr = &a` means `ptr` is a variable of type `int *` which has been assigned `&a`

And `*ptr = a` means `variable stored at address ptr` (dereferencing `ptr`) which is being assigned `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!