# Getting error when trying to malloc memory to pointer variable declared separately

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have declared a char pointer in the following manner:

```
School *student[10];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    *student[i] = malloc(sizeof(Student));   <--- Error points here
}
```

The error I get is:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Student' from type 'void*'
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

But how come if I were to allocate memory in the same line it would be with the star. For example: `Student *name = malloc(sizeof(Student));` Why does this work? Im a bit confused

Comment: There is no `char` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*student[i] = malloc(sizeof(School));` should be `student[i] = malloc(sizeof(School));`

`students` is an array of pointer to struct of type `School`. So you need to allocate for each pointer in that array. When you write `*student[i]` - you are dereferencing pointer `i` instead of allocating memory for it.

And as NicolasMiari pointed out, the `sizeof` operator must apply to `School` instead of `student`.

> But how come if I were to allocate memory in the same line it would be with the star. For example: Student *name = malloc(sizeof(Student)); Why does this work? Im a bit confused

That's different. When you write `Student *name = malloc(sizeof(Student));` you are both declaring a pointer and **initialize** it with `malloc`. You can do both steps in a single line like that. Alternatively, you declare it first, then **assign** it with `malloc` in a different line - in that case you must remove the asterisk.

You may want to refer to this question [pointer initialization and pointer assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654561/assigning-an-address-to-a-pointer/34654643#34654643).

Comment: Indeed, the asterisk should go. However, shouldn't it be either School or Student in both occurrences?

Comment: yes it's. I didn't catch that - thanks.

Comment: @artm But how come if I were to allocate memory in the same line it would be with the star. For example: Student *name = malloc(sizeof(Student)); Why does this work? Im a bit confused